# How to indicate a condition in sum?

Tags: summation, notation

I want to sum over all the possible combinations of two numbers that give the same result under a certain formula. Specifically, in this case, sum over all the possible combinations of non-negative integers $i,j\in\mathbb{N}_0$ that together with some constant natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ give the same value for the formula $k=n\left(i+j\right)+j$.

I tried the following notation:

$$\sum_{k=n\left(i+j\right)+j}2^k$$ 
But, it seems somewhat ambiguous and unclear, it's not explicit how many and what variables the sum goes over and which are fixed. How do I indicate exactly and clearly my intentions?
Maybe something like:

$${\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}}_{s.t\ n\left(i+j\right)+j=k}2^k$$

Comment: I sometimes write $\sum_{k \in I} \text{blah}$ and then describe the index set $I$ explicitly.

Comment: Your link just points to this same question.

Comment: @RobPratt, sorry, my bad. This is related to my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526286/how-many-different-combinations-of-non-negative-integers-i-j-can-give-the-sam

Comment: Is $k$ a fix number or not? If it is, then $2^k$ is also a constant and it could be taken out of the summation. If it is not, why is not your sum infinite?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, yes, it's a fixed number and it can be taken out of the sum and put $1$ inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " I want to sum (*what ?*) over all the possible combinations of two numbers .."

the *what* shall be a function $f \, : \, \mathbb {Z}^2 \to \mathbb X$ so you write
$$
S(C) = \sum\limits_{(i,j)\, \in \,C} {f(i,j)} 
$$
where $C$ is a domain in the plane $i,j$ defined by certain conditions.

In the example you give, 
$$
C = \left\{ {(i,j):\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le i,j \hfill \cr 
  n\left( {i + j} \right) + j = k \hfill \cr}  \right.} \right\}
$$
where $n$ and $k$ are considered as given **constants** (or parameters), and do not vary while taking the sum.

So by writing
$$
S(C) = \sum\limits_{(i,j)\, \in \,C} {2^{\,k} } 
$$
you are actually telling
$$
S(C) = \sum\limits_{(i,j)\, \in \,C} {2^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{(i,j)\, \in \,C} {2^{\,k}  \cdot 1}  = 2^{\,k} \sum\limits_{(i,j)\,} {{\bf 1}_{\left\{ {(i,j)\, \in \,C} \right\}} }  = 2^{\,k} \left| C \right|
$$
i.e., that $f(i,j)=1$, so that when summed over $C$ i it is equivalent to summing the corresponding [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)
over the whole plane, and finally to give the size of $C$, which is the number of non-negative solutions to the diophantine equation $n\left( {i + j} \right) + j = k$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option, using \substack:
$$\sum_{\substack{i\ge 0,\ j\ge 0:\\n\left(i+j\right)+j=k}} 2^k$$

Comment: The first option says something else entirely, the condition is nowhere to be found and gives a completely different answer (specifically $\infty$). The second one is still messy and not clear.

Comment: So $k$ is fixed?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the number of different combinations for a certain $k$ and $n$, for example, for $n=3$, for $k=1,2$ the number is $0$, for $k=4$ it's $1$, and for $k=12$ it's $2$

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to remove the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Following your answer to my comment, I would suggest to write
$$
2^k \bigl|\bigl\{(i,j) \in {\Bbb N}^2 \mid ni + (n+1)j = k\bigr\}\bigr|
$$